# R: knitr + RGL: Issues with visreg's visreg2d function

Tags: r, knitr, rgl

I am trying to create an RGL plot using the `visreg2d` function of the `visreg` package in R, to include into an HTML document created by running `knitr` on an RMarkdown file.

I am able to get RGL plots from `rgl` package functions `plot3d` and `spheres3d` but not from a call to `visreg2d(..., plot.type = "rgl")` in my HTML document.

Here is a sample RMarkdown file, built up from the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23021317/1414455):

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: no
---
```{r setup, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(rsm)
library(visreg)

knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
cat('<script type="text/javascript">', readLines(system.file('WebGL', 'CanvasMatrix.js', package = 'rgl')), '</script>', sep = '\n')
```

This works fine.

```{r testgl, webgl=TRUE}
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
```

This one also works.

```{r testgl2, webgl=TRUE}
open3d()
spheres3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
```

```{r, webGL = TRUE}
library(rsm)
swiss2.lm <- lm(Fertility ~ Agriculture*Education, data = swiss)
open3d()
visreg2d(swiss2.lm, "Education", "Agriculture", plot.type = "rgl")
```
````

The calls to `plot3d` and `spheres3d` work but not the one to `visreg2d`. That is, even though locally I can see the RGL plot, it does not get embedded in my HTML document. Any advice on how to get that working will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a typo -- you've typed `webGL = TRUE` instead of `webgl=TRUE`.

However, I will add that when I tried this on my machine, I had to reduce the resolution of the visreg plot (otherwise I ran into "stack space overflow" errors) using the `nn` option to `visreg2d` (e.g.,`nn=39`).